# Netbeans won't start-up - 7.4

Tags: netbeans

I force shutdown my pc by holding down the power button till it went off. Just before it shutdown, I saw a netbeans pop-up just come up before the system went off. Before initializing the shutdown, I had closed netbeans, and I think that netbeans had not fully shutdown. The pop-up might have been the last procedure the IDE automatically does, like those that flash the cmd which almost immediately closes by itself.

The problem is that now netbeans won't start up. It only shows the blue window then dissapears, not to appear again, even in the task manager.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would try some basic things like another restart, check your task manager see if the process is running (end it and try again), or you can just reinstall netbeans no big deal

Comment: @Ljubisa Would I be able to keep the netbeans modules I had if I do uninstall?

Comment: I believe so however I am not 100% sure :(

Comment: @user3719487-Sometimes, this kinda things happen if you don't quit the programs properly. It might have lost the major application and resulting in crash.Why don't you re-install the NetbeansIDE;your modules would be safe-if you don't trust,you whould better keep a backup of your modules.

Comment: Launch from CLI and check out the output.